# on equilibirum solutions of a ordinary differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given

$$ t x' = (1 - 4t^2) \tan x $$

Easily, by separation of variables, we obtain

$$ x(t) = \arcsin( C t e^{-2t^2}) $$

However, $x = 0, \pi/2, ... $ are also solution, equilibirum solutions. This is the answer given in the book which I think should also include the equilibrium solutions as well. Maybe, do we need to specify the interval where $x$ lies to avoid having equilibrium solutions?

Comment: Actually the solutions are such that $$\sin x(t)=Cte^{-2t^2}$$ which is not the same thing as what you write. For example, $$x(t)=\pi$$ is a solution although no real number $u$ solves $\pi=\arcsin u$. Additionally, $\sin x=0$ is solved by $$x\in\pi\mathbb Z$$ not by $x\in\frac\pi2\mathbb Z$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $x(t)=\pi/2$ is not a solution, since the right hand side is not defined. The equilibrium solutions are $x(t)=k\,\pi$, $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. They are obtained from the general solution by letting $C=0$.